# How do I avoid duplicates or near-duplicate results with Atlas Vector Search (MongoDB)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, vector-search

I'm using Atlas Vector Search to retrieve k nearest neighbours, exactly like it is described here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/field-types/knn-vector/.

The database is created using embeddings via OpenAI.

However, for a given query, the vector search returns many very similar matches (sometimes exact matches, sometimes only a word has changed). And I'd like to have a more diverse result set.

As far as I can see, Atlas Vector Search doesn't yet support Maximal Marginal Relevance (MMR) or similar algorithms.

Any hints what to do here?